# trying to download a dataset from a website

Tags: apache, download, web, server, fedora

I am trying to download a dataset from a website but I can't download the whole folder .. I have to download each file separately which will need a lot of time. I am wondering if there is anyway to download the whole folder at a time??

The website link: http://www.physionet.org/pn4/eegmmidb/

Comment: You could probably write code that would do it by parsing the list of links and making requests to the URLs.

Comment: The problem is that I am not a good at website programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two for cycles run in bash should do it:

```
for S in S{001..109}; do
   mkdir ${S}
   cd ${S}
   for R in R{01..14}; do
      file="http://www.physionet.org/pn4/eegmmidb/${S}/${S}${R}.edf"
      wget "$file"
      wget "${file}.event"
   done
   cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use wget with the -r switch to turn on mirroring.

This command will do what you want:

wget --no-parent -r  http://www.physionet.org/pn4/eegmmidb/

It'll produce a mirror copy of everything from that directory on down.